# C# - Windows Mobile - Bluetooth Pairing

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-mobile-6

I've been given the task of building a Windows Mobile app for our company that quickly pairs a device by scanning it's bar code. I can discover the device, and talk to it, but I am stuck as far as pairing.

In C# / Windows Mobile 6, how do I pair a device? I don't really need to talk to the device within the app, I need to pair it so other applications can use it.

Is there an API I need to do this? I've seen things saying I need to register a pass key, etc? I can't seem to find any documentation on the actual pairing process, just connecting to it. (Just connecting to it, doesn't actually pair it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my library [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/).  Use method `BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest` See e.g. [Bluetooth Security](http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bluetooth%20Security) (That should work regardless of whether the device has Microsoft's own Bluetooth stack installed or the device has Widcomm/Broadcom or SSO Bluetopia).

The process of 'pairing' should also enable the services at the same time.  If not we probably have other APIs for that too.  Which services are used?  SerialPort, others?

Comment: I've tried using this before, but I'm assuming I'm doing it wrong. I'm relatively new to Windows Mobile development, and when I tried running it, the app would just hang forever. Is there any specific examples of implementation?

Comment: alanjmcf: I'm trying to pair a Zebra printer. It needs to be paired on COM1 to work with existing applications.

Comment: Reason I couldn't get it to work before is for a multitude of reasons. 1) I was using Zebra's SDK which was causing conflicts. 2) I was using the wrong dll file. There are two in the package that I downloaded.