# Is it possible to trigger bluetooth service re-enumeration on Windows 8/8.1?

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, windows-8.1

When trying to programatically pair a bluetooth device with the inthehand.net library, I've noticed that my device ended up in Devices and printers as a "Generic bluetooth device" with none of its SDP records queried.

- Pairing, enumeration and PANU connection setup succeeds on windows 7
- Only pairing seems to succeed on windows 8.1, a serviceless device is added to devices & printers.
- Querying PANU using the inthehand lib works fine after establishing the pairing, however windows does not acknowledge this (the device in devices & printers has no connect/direct connection)

Related (?):

[Is there an API call to start a scan for hardware devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181525/is-there-an-api-call-to-start-a-scan-for-hardware-devices?newreg=809475bf1a494a15a3e5ea1848f0afbc)
[C# - Windows Mobile - Bluetooth Pairing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518307/c-sharp-windows-mobile-bluetooth-pairing/24043144?noredirect=1#comment37068131_24043144)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

- On Windows 7 the services (PANU) are enumerated and added during the pairing process.
- On Windows 8.1 calling SetServiceState (via inthehand) after pairing the device resolves my issue.